# Where can I find constants in my xdebug session?

Tags: php, xdebug

Recently I was looking for some constants variable in my xdebug session but I didn't find them. Only way I can see them is the watch variable menu. Isn't it a constant a super global? Where can I find them?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864067/how-do-i-examine-defined-constants-in-php Doesn't look you can view constants in xdebug, but you can set a var of what's been defined up to that point.

Comment: Can you make an answer? I give you vote?

Comment: Thankssssssss! (15 character min is weird)

Comment: Just a note that Xdebug 2.3+ shows user consts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011922/constants-shown-in-xdebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [How do I examine defined constants in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864067/how-do-i-examine-defined-constants-in-php)

Doesn't look you can view constants in xdebug, but you can set a var of what's been defined up to that point.