# Getting value of define()s

Tags: php, vim, xdebug

I am debugging a PHP application that uses many `define()` functions. Is there any way to get the values of `define()` later in the code where the identifier is used? `F11` only shows conventional variables, and `F12` on the defined identifier returns only the identifier name.

This is with xdebug 2.1.0 on PHP 5.3 running on Ubuntu Server 12.04, as used in VIM 7.3. Thanks!

Comment: I am looking to get the output in the xdebug console in VIM, not printed to stdout. I suppose that in a pinch I could add `$someVar = var_export(get_defined_constants(true), true)` and then check the content of `$someVar` in xdebug, but I would prefer to use native Xdebug functionality without changing the application code.

Comment: Thank you FDL, if the problem is an xdebug limitation and not a VIM implementation limitation, then this is in fact a dupe. As different xdebug features might not be exposed in Netbeans or VIM, I'll dig in a bit and mark it as a dupe if that is the case. Thank you for finding that!

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried it with Xdebug and netbeans but named constants values didn't show up.

Possible solution already given here:

[How do I examine defined constants in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864067/how-do-i-examine-defined-constants-in-php)

Moreover, you can try to contact directly

`xdebug-general@lists.xdebug.org`

to check; may be they have some workaround.

Comment: Thank you Umair. The solutions on that page only output the defined constants to a variable: no direct access. I will ask on the xdebug list, that is probably a good bet!