# How can I view the array of constants defined by the foreach loop?

Tags: php

Maybe this is a simple question but I'm just getting started with and wondering how can I var_dump all the contestants that I create by looping them? Here's my code.

```
$database['db-host'] = 'localhost';
$database['db-user'] = 'root';
$database['db-pass'] = 'root';
$database['db-name'] = 'my_db';


foreach ($database as $details => $values) {

    define(strtoupper($details), $values);

}
```

I can view them individually with `var_dump('DB_USER');` but was wondering how can I view them all as an array created by this `foreach` loop?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864067/how-do-i-examine-defined-constants-in-php is what you are after?

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks, this shows all of them defined, I'm getting a huge list, any way to show just the one I create with the loop?

Comment: @AbdUrRehman: why you wanted as group, why not just pass this variable `$database` where you wanted as global ?

Comment: @AbdUrRehman: use `db_host` underscore instead `db-host` dash

Comment: @RishiRaut Thanks, I noticed that too, best to use underscore instead of a dash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you could just say that the constants added are the ones defined in `$database`.  But as a strict answer to how to find the ones defined in the loop, you could store the constants defined before the loop, then after and look at the differences (using `array_diff()`)...

```
$database['db-host'] = 'localhost';
$database['db-user'] = 'root';
$database['db-pass'] = 'root';
$database['db-name'] = 'my_db';

$beforeConstants = get_defined_constants();
foreach ($database as $details => $values) {
    define(strtoupper($details), $values);
}
$afterConstants = get_defined_constants();

print_r(array_diff($afterConstants, $beforeConstants));
```

should give

```
Array
(
    [DB-HOST] => localhost
    [DB-USER] => root
    [DB-PASS] => root
    [DB-NAME] => my_db
)
```

Comment: you made it right, but I think why so much exercise, he can use array as global and get those values as one array. ie (`define('DB_SETTINGS',$database)`) and get those values as `DB_SETTINGS`